# Can we put an checkbox in an alert box?

Tags: javascript

Can we put an check box in a standard windows alert box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do that but you can make use of [**jQuery dialog plugin**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) or you can create your cutome model box for this ...